# When will this code terminate?

Tags: java, concurrency

This code is from Java Concurrency In Practice and is talking about Noncancelable tasks. I can't figure out when the code inside the `finally` block will ever run, won't the `while(true)` loop continue forever unless some other exception is thrown?

```
/**
 * NoncancelableTask
 * <p/>
 * Noncancelable task that restores interruption before exit
 *
 * @author Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class NoncancelableTask {
    public Task getNextTask(BlockingQueue<Task> queue) {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        try {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    return queue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    interrupted = true;
                    // fall through and retry
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (interrupted)
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    interface Task {
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a `return` statement inside the loop.

Comment: Ah, missed that, thanks, I think I'm half asleep.